# delete multiple rows in gridview using checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have used following code to execute my query of deleting multiple values in gridview using checkboxes but when i execute the following it says checkbox1.checked is false but i check that . It doesnot delte my selected values

here is my code and script part

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        grd_bnd();
    }
}
 private void grd_bnd()
{
 SqlConnection con = new        SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from student", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("checkboxdelete");
        if (checkbox1.Checked)
        {
            int rollno = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            //CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("checkbox1");
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from student where rollno = @rollno ", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@rollno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rollno.ToString();
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
    grd_bnd();
}
}
```

and here is script

```
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="rollno" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkboxdelete" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>' /> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roll No.">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblrollno" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("rollno") %>' /> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Batch">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblbatch" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("batch") %>' /> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Course">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcourse" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("course") %>' /> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        </gridview>
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Delete Selected" ForeColor="#000066" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#666666"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this way

```
       for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
        CheckBox checkboxdelete = ((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("checkboxdelete"));

        if (checkboxdelete.Checked == true)
        {
            Label lblrollno = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblrollno"));

            int rolNo = Convert.ToInt32(lblrollno.Text);
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from student where rollno = @rollno ", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@rollno", SqlDbType.Int);
            param.Value = rolNo;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
      }
```

Comment: i should try it instead of for each or inside foreach?

Comment: @mohit debug your page ? wheres the issue arising

Comment: when i use both for and foreach it agains says checkbox.checked is false

Comment: @mohit RollNO is Int OR string in database

Comment: it is not entring in if (chechbox1.checked) , it is just passing outside

Comment: what u say i dont understand

Comment: i say when i use breakpoint,it shows that  is not entering "if" command

Comment: @mohit your all code is replace with my code  or not ?

Comment: sir problem is not that i am not getting the value prob is that it is not entering if  i have taken help of examples where they say it is done like this only but in my case it doesnot enters in if(checkbox1.checked == true)

Comment: @mohit please you edit your question with new code after changing

Comment: i have posted my new question

Comment: @mohit i show it first of all you dont write SqlParameter  and also you pass roll no as string,it is wrong,i alredy try your problem in my side and its work fine So you replace your code with my code

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is below code on button click event:

```
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox checkboxdelete = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("checkboxdelete");
        if (checkboxdelete.Checked == true)
        {
            using (SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString))
            {
                scon.Open();
                Label LblId = (Label)row.FindControl("rollno");
                int rollno = Convert.ToInt32(LblId.Text);
                SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("delete from student where rollno = @rollno", scon);
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rollno", rollno);
                scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                scon.Close();
                BindGrid();
                Label4.Text = "";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label4.Text = "No record is selected to delete !";
            Label4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
```