# How can we bind data while calling WCF method through stored procedures as I am getting null values for all the parameters while debugging

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, wcf

Parameters in stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DeleteRecords]
   @TBL_ID varchar(2000),
   @ACCT_ID int,
   @SEQ_NUM Char (4),
   @CMNT_TXT varchar (100)
```

WCF method mentioned

```
public void DeleteCollPolicies(string strCollPolicyIds ,int CollAcctID,string Term_Seq_Num, string Iteration_Cmnt_Text)
{
    SqlParameter[] sqlParameter = new SqlParameter[4];
       
    sqlParameter[0] = new SqlParameter("@TBL_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2000, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "TBL_POL_COLL_AGMT_DTLS_ID", DataRowVersion.Current, strCollPolicyIds);
    sqlParameter[1] = new SqlParameter("@COLL_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "COLL_ID", DataRowVersion.Current, CollAcctID);
    sqlParameter[2] = new SqlParameter("@SEQ_NUM", SqlDbType.Char, 4, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "SEQ_NUM", DataRowVersion.Current, Term_Seq_Num);
    sqlParameter[3] = new SqlParameter("@CMNT_TXT", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "CMNT_TXT ", DataRowVersion.Current, Iteration_Cmnt_Text);

    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(strConnStr, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "DeleteRecords", sqlParameter);

    // return listdata;
    // return Convert.ToInt32(sqlParameter[4].Value);
}
```

Finally the `Delete` method with binding WCF method

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strCollPolicyIds = string.Empty;
    string Seq_Num = string.Empty;
    string Cmnt_Text = string.Empty;
    int cctID = ThisWorkbook.AccountId ;
                          
    int total = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(p => Convert.ToBoolean(p.Cells["chkbox"].Value) == true).Count();

    if (total > 0)
    {
        string message = $"Are you sure want to delete {total} row?";
        if (total >= 1)
        {
            message = $"Are you sure want to delete {total}rows";

            if (MessageBox.Show(message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    // "1,2,3"
                    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];

                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["chkbox"].Value) == true)
                    {
                        ServClient.DeleteCollPolicies(strCollPolicyIds, AcctID, Seq_Num, Cmnt_Text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So here in this method while debugging I am getting null values for all 4 parameters

Comment: Can you show the code for your `SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery` method? Are you sure you're not getting an error since, as far as parameter names go, `@COLL_ID` != `@ACCT_ID`.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning the parameters I just changed  from Original as per Data Privacy but actually all are same naming convention

Comment: and this the WCF Method  for deleting but not sure why I am not able to see any values while debugging ,could you please help me

Comment: what  have shared in Post WCF Method with SP name that is only  SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery or do you want to know anything more please let me know

Comment: The spelling of the parameter in your DeleteCollPolicies method is inconsistent (in many places the spelling is inconsistent, I suggest you breakpoint to check that int cctID = ThisWorkbook.AccountId has a value).

Comment: You set the parameter to be empty at first, and then there is no assignment, so it is a null value. You can refer to how others deleted it.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131532/delete-multiple-rows-in-gridview-using-checkboxes

Comment: Yes I am getting value only for int ccid = ThisWorkbook.AccountID but rest of the parameters values are null ,that is only challenge how can I get those value too . Here just for information this windows based application and in winform I am binding with one datasource called colpolinfo through which I am able get all the date in winform gridview and now from that grid view itself by selecting checkbox i need to delete one or more rows .Please Suggest @Lan Huang It would be great help